# VBA: how to account for WEEKNUM 2019 values when applying text

Tags: vba, excel, week-number

I have a column that records WEEKNUM weeks (this week is week 28) and then if the value is less than this week, then it is labeled as "Late". The code works fine, but some of the weeks that are less than this week are in 2019. I included an example picture below to showcase what I am doing. I am not sure how to adjust my VBA to account for 2019 values.

```
With isum.workSheets("Orders")
With .Range(.Cells(2, "X"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 9))
    .Formula = "=weeknum(o2)"
    .NumberFormat = "0_)"
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=x2<weeknum(today())")
        .NumberFormat = "L\at\e_)"
    End With
End With
```

End With

[image: The WEEKNUM formula is applied to the receiving date]

Comment: Why not add the year number to the start and format the week number with 2 significant figures?

Comment: What would be an efficient way to go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
...
... , Formula1:="=and(x2<weeknum(today()), year(o2)=year(today()))")
...
```